# Exact mechanical location of pin1 on J8 of raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi

Designing HAT for Rpi3.

I am looking for precise dimensions of Pin1 of J8 on Raspberry pi 3 board, relative to the mounting holes.
No luck finding this after hours ..........

Any help is much appreciated !!
rob

Answer (score 1):

This was right on google, but I'll post it anyway:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/mechanical/README.md

You have PDF's and DXF's the DXF's should prove most useful if you have a reader, because you could use a cad program to draw dimensions on the DXF.

[image]

Keep in mind its just a 0.1" header, they are pretty standard, the drawing only gives the outside dimensions but the inside dimensions can be calculated if you use some intuition and logic on the centerlines and the outside of the rectangle. I don't know if the mechanical drawing given is the silkscreen or part outline, but if you go off of the centerline it should be fine. Keep in mind there are a few mills of space for through hole parts so your tolerance on that dimension will be roughly 5mils.

Comment: Thanks for Replying LapTop2d. Yes I had already found those. No precise mechanical info in those docs re my question. Yes I can do the "assumption and estimate" thing. But the "answer is out there" and guessing and estimating is a way to end up with a layout that "almost works" :-(  So I will keep looking.

Comment: The tolerances are only going to be a few mils anyway. Any PCB tech I know would be fine with those drawings. If you have to get a rasberri pi and measure it yourself with calipers. Why do you have to have every dimension spelled out? Sometimes they are wrong anyway.

Comment: The DXF contains the numerical data since it is a drawing, it's just not written out like on an old blueprint.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for relying.

I downloaded a DXF reader, blew up the undimensioned drawing, made a screen shot of the blow up, imported into my mech program, scaled the distance between the 100 mil pins, then i (effectively) measured the the distance from the center line of the connector pins to the center of the mounting hole.

It is 0.19182 inches, which is 480 mm exactly. That's a freaking lot of work that looking at a dimensioned dwg could reveal in a second.

BTW, I have made thousands of PCBs in my 47 year career and I disagree with you that the positioning would only be good to a few mils. If that were true, many through hole parts will not fit. Yes, you can make fat sloppy holes (oversized holes), but that is ... well ... sloppy. That's not me. 
Thanks again.

Comment: Too bad your DXF-reader doesn't support measuring :( Any program that displays drawings should have such a feature!

Comment: Most cad programs will